# Optical flow in Android

Tags: android, opencv, vision, opticalflow

We have been dealing with OpenCV for two weeks to make it work on Android.
Do you know where can we find an Android implementation of optical flow? It would be nice if it's implemented using OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```java
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    if (mMOP2fptsPrev.rows() == 0) {

        //Log.d("Baz", "First time opflow");
        // first time through the loop so we need prev and this mats
        // plus prev points
        // get this mat
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, matOpFlowThis, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

        // copy that to prev mat
        matOpFlowThis.copyTo(matOpFlowPrev);

        // get prev corners
        Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(matOpFlowPrev, MOPcorners, iGFFTMax, 0.05, 20);
        mMOP2fptsPrev.fromArray(MOPcorners.toArray());

        // get safe copy of this corners
        mMOP2fptsPrev.copyTo(mMOP2fptsSafe);
        }
    else
        {
        //Log.d("Baz", "Opflow");
        // we've been through before so
        // this mat is valid. Copy it to prev mat
        matOpFlowThis.copyTo(matOpFlowPrev);

        // get this mat
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, matOpFlowThis, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

        // get the corners for this mat
        Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(matOpFlowThis, MOPcorners, iGFFTMax, 0.05, 20);
        mMOP2fptsThis.fromArray(MOPcorners.toArray());

        // retrieve the corners from the prev mat
        // (saves calculating them again)
        mMOP2fptsSafe.copyTo(mMOP2fptsPrev);

        // and save this corners for next time through

        mMOP2fptsThis.copyTo(mMOP2fptsSafe);
        }


    /*
    Parameters:
        prevImg first 8-bit input image
        nextImg second input image
        prevPts vector of 2D points for which the flow needs to be found; point coordinates must be single-precision floating-point numbers.
        nextPts output vector of 2D points (with single-precision floating-point coordinates) containing the calculated new positions of input features in the second image; when OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW flag is passed, the vector must have the same size as in the input.
        status output status vector (of unsigned chars); each element of the vector is set to 1 if the flow for the corresponding features has been found, otherwise, it is set to 0.
        err output vector of errors; each element of the vector is set to an error for the corresponding feature, type of the error measure can be set in flags parameter; if the flow wasn't found then the error is not defined (use the status parameter to find such cases).
    */
    Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(matOpFlowPrev, matOpFlowThis, mMOP2fptsPrev, mMOP2fptsThis, mMOBStatus, mMOFerr);

    cornersPrev = mMOP2fptsPrev.toList();
    cornersThis = mMOP2fptsThis.toList();
    byteStatus = mMOBStatus.toList();

    y = byteStatus.size() - 1;

    for (x = 0; x < y; x++) {
        if (byteStatus.get(x) == 1) {
            pt = cornersThis.get(x);
            pt2 = cornersPrev.get(x);


            Core.circle(mRgba, pt, 5, colorRed, iLineThickness - 1);

            Core.line(mRgba, pt, pt2, colorRed, iLineThickness);
            }
        }

return mRgba;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Openframeworks has openCV baked in, as well as many other interesting libraries. It has a very elegant strucutre, and I have used it with android to make a virtual mouse of the phone using motion estimation from the camera.

See the ports to android here http://openframeworks.cc/setup/android-studio/

Seems they recently added support for android studio, otherwise eclipse works great.